# Python script just printing out blank page

Tags: python, xampp, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am using xampp and I am able to run simple python script on it so xampp is setup fine for python. I am trying to use pillow.

I have installed anaconda and did following in terminal

```
 conda install pillow
```

If I run test.py below in terminal, it works fine. It prints format, size, mode.

But if I try it from web browser I'm getting blank page.

Here is test.py

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/anaconda/bin/python

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><head><title>Python</title></head><body>")
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
original = Image.open("Lenna.png")
print("<h5>The size of the Image is: </h5>")
print("<h2>size " + original.format, original.size, original.mode + "</h2>")
```

if I use cgitb.enable() I get following error

```
    A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/test7.py in ()
      8 print("<html><head><title>Python</title></head><body>");
      9 print("<h5>The size of the Image is: </h5>");
=>   10 from PIL import Image
     11 original = Image.open("Lenna.png");
     12 width, height = original.size;
PIL undefined, Image undefined
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in ()
     61     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     62     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
=>   63     from PIL import _imaging as core
     64     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     65         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "
PIL undefined, _imaging undefined, core = <PIL.Image._imaging_not_installed object>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libtiff.5.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0 
      args = ('dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Vers...later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0',) 
      msg = 'dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Vers...later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0' 
      name = '_imaging' 
      path = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so' 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of ImportError object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an anti-answer, but unless you are doing it this way for academic reasons, you should try one of the more standard frameworks:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/)
- [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)

The two frameworks I listed above are examples of minimalist frameworks that do not get in your way. They take care of running your app and setting up routes. The minimum to use Flask is this:

```
from flask import Flask
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def myview():
    original = Image.open("Lenna.png")

    return """
        <html><head><title>Python</title></head>
        <body>
        <h5>The size of the Image is: </h5>
        <h2>size {format}, {size}, {mode}</h2>
        </body></html>""".format(
            format=original.format,
            size=original.size,
            mode=original.mode)

app.run()
```

Next, if you want to make your app available, you only need to setup a reverse proxy in XAMPP (easy-peasy). I highly suggest using Flask; it comes with an awesome in-page debugger, courtesy of its sister project [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) (lit. "toolbox").

### Werkzeug debugger:

[image: Werkzeug debugger]

Comment: Do you mean you are looking into Python scripting for academic reasons, or you are trying to do it the way you are doing it now (not recommended) specifically for academic reasons?

Comment: I'm doing it for academic reasons, I've to use pillow library for my assignment. I tried cgitb.enable(), I'm getting this error "Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0 "